# Blur the camera at a particular point Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-2dtools

I used the blur on some objects using several cameras and different layers to blur. And it is not difficult. But how to make the blur around a specific point that will move with the character?

Thanks in advance...

Update! 
I found what I needed, and this shader called as a Tilt Shift! But it is not optimized for mobile platforms. So the question remains open.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will basically need to use the same technique.

You need to have a second camera capture a separate, blurred layer, and have it render on an object. That object you can move around as you please.

This technique is described in this official Video Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ll6UP-kG40&feature=youtu.be&t=1h

Comment: it's not exactly what I need